# Não consigo usar a Hospedagem no Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm

Quando tento fazer a hospedagem usando o "firebase init" e depois escolho o projeto e o e o host, aplico o "firebase deploy" mas quando eu abro o link aparece essa tela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que devo fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a própria [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart?hl=pt-br), ao digitar o comando `firebase init`, será solicitado para você selecionar uma pasta na raiz do projeto onde ficarão os arquivos estáticos. O padrão é `public`.

Se você não tiver nenhum `index.html` lá, será criado para você. De uma olhada lá. Esse layout aparecendo ai, provavelmente é o padrão criado pelo **Firebase**.